# Listview items displayed should not be greater than 20

Tags: android, listview, adapter, display

How to restrict list view to just show `20` items and if 21st item comes then the last item is replaced by 21st item so that only `20` items are shown at a time.

I searched for it and found that if we write in the adapter like below then it will show only `20` items

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 20;
}
```

but if i write this the app force closed saying **index is 0 and size is 0**.
Please help me what to do

Comment: in getCount method check the size of your list if size is greater than 20 than return 20 else return list.size()

Comment: you should never return a fixed value. What will happens if your dataset contains less then the n items you are returning ? You will get a IndexOutBoundException

Comment: Are you asking about Pagination?

Comment: @NavinGupta Thankyou it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Something like :**

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
return list.size > 20 : 20 ? list.size() ;
}
```

Comment: yes it works :) will make it accepted after 5 mins :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
public class TestAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static int sMaxArraySize = 20;

    private List<String> mData = new ArrayList<>(sMaxArraySize);

    public void addNewItem(String string) {
        if (mData.size() == sMaxArraySize) {
            mData.remove(0);
        }

        mData.add(string);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Don't forget call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after `addNewItem()`